# function for complex assignment of number to letters

Tags: r, string, function, dplyr

ORIGINAL QUESTION: I'm struggeling to write a function for assigning numbers to letters under complex conditions. Please have a look at the example tibble. I need a way to get the values in df$nr.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-tibble(word=c(rep("Hobbies", 17), rep("tate", 11)),
            let=c("H1","H1","H2","H2","o","o","b","b","b","b","i","i","e","e","iP","iP","s",
                  "t1","t1","a","a","t1","t1","e","e","t2","t2","t2"),
            tra=c(NA,"H2",NA,"o",NA,"b",NA,"b",NA,"i",NA,"e",NA,"iP",NA,"s",NA,
                  NA,"a",NA,"t1",NA,"e",NA,"t2",NA,"t2",NA),
            nr= c(1,1,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6,6,6.5,7,
                  1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4,4,4,4) )
```

UPDATE / SOLUTION
I'm not using a function, but I found a solution based on `dplyr::case_when`. There are still two errors: `In eval_bare(f[[2]], env) : NAs introduced by coercion`. They come from checking a substring that's not present in all cases, but I don't know how to get rid of them.

```
df <- df %>%  
  group_by(word) %>%  
  mutate(  
    test = cumsum(  
      case_when (  
        # first letter per word -> 1  
        row_number()==1L                            ~ 1,  
        # tra is NA -> full letter, should result in an integer in the end  
        # special case: dots (e.g. on 'i' -> "iP", this is not a full letter -> do nothing  
        is.na(tra) & str_sub(let,2,2)=="P"          ~ 0,  
        # special case: fraction of a letter (e.g. "H2" or "t2"), i.e. number is > 1 -> do nothing  
        is.na(tra) & as.integer(str_sub(let,2,2))>1 ~ 0,  
        # full letter -> 0.5  
        is.na(tra)                                  ~ 0.5,  
        # tra is present -> trajectory towards next letter, should result in .5 in the end  
        # special case: tra to dot -> do nothing  
        str_sub(tra,2,2)=="P"                       ~ 0,  
        # special case: tra to fraction -> do nothing  
        as.integer(str_sub(tra,2,2))>1              ~ 0,  
        # all other tra  
        TRUE                                        ~ 0.5  
        )  
      )  
    )  

all.equal(df$nr, df$test)  
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This looks like a situation where ```dplyr::case_when``` would help. But then you have a lot of nasty regex to deal with and the stringr package might help.

Comment: @markhogue Thanks, will have a look at `case_when` then.

Comment: Can you provide a higher level explanation of what you're trying to accomplish with the pseudocode?

Comment: @Roger-123 Found a solution myself and commented it. There's still an error but the result is OK.